# Strange behavior. Two identical http requests work differently

Tags: authentication, go, http

I'm trying to use one service via rest api and I'm running into very strange behavior - when I send a request via curl/Postman everything works, but when I send a request with Golang I get a 401.
I will not point out the service as it does not matter, it is important to understand why seemingly identical requests work differently.

Curl:

```
curl --location 'https://example/v1/endpoint' \
--header 'Authorization: b25c7f72e1ccb95a8520:MmM5ZGQxYjU4ZDA3MmZkMTI5MTFhMDY0MzZhOGQ2ZjM4MDVhMTk0ZQ==' \
--header 'User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1' \
--header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip'
```

Go example:

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    r, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://example/v1/endpoint", nil)
    r.Header.Set("Authorization", "b25c7f72e1ccb95a8520:MmM5ZGQxYjU4ZDA3MmZkMTI5MTFhMDY0MzZhOGQ2ZjM4MDVhMTk0ZQ==")

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(r)

    fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode, err) //401, nil
}
```

Requests are launched from the same machine.
I used a proxy to get both requests and compare them. They look absolutely identical.
But it's impossible if the behavior is different, isn't it? I assumed that there might be a problem in the encoding of the Authorization header, but in the proxy it looks fine.
Can you tell what might be the difference?

Postman:
[image]

Go:
[image]

Absolutely identical (including the ip that I covered up).

Comment: How come the first screenshot says postman but the user agent is Go client?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Can you see my curl example? I added this header manually so that the requests are the same.

Comment: Neither request has an [`<auth-scheme>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization#syntax) prefixing the credentials so I'm surprised the Postman request works.

Comment: @DazWilkin It also depends on the receiving service. If they decide to do this authorization without specifying the scheme, I think this is their right.

Comment: *"I used a proxy to get both requests and compare them."* - so the requests are send from the proxy to the server when you observe the behavior? Or do you observe it only when the requests are sent directly w/o proxy? In the latter case changes in the TLS stack or support for HTTP/1 vs. HTTP/2 might lead to a difference, which is not shown in the proxy (which seems to support only HTTP/1)

Comment: how did a proxy get the request headers if this is https?